# assistance regarding fetching and displaying a display:none back to my page

Tags: javascript, button, input, fetch-api

this is my code:

```
const clcBtn = document.getElementById("calcButton");
let clcInput = document.getElementById("calcInput");
const result = document.getElementById('paragraph');
const loader = document.getElementById('spinner');
clcBtn.addEventListener("click", calcFunc);
function calcFunc() {
  loader.classList.add("display")
  fetch(`http://localhost:5050/fibonacci/`).then(function (response) {
    return response.json().then(function (data) {
      result.innerHTML = data.clcInput.value; // i want to get the input value from the input field and the server to calculate it and present it to the user.
    });
  });
}
```

basically what i want to do, is to add the value the user types in to the innerHTML paragraph id name.
and then i want to make the button react to the click and re-display the "loader" (which i gave it display:none in the CSS file)
and then, i need to make the button to display an error message if the input is higher than 50.

what i have tried to do:

inside the

> clcBtn.addEventListener("click", calcFunc);
> function calcFunc() {

i have tried to add:

```
loader.classlist.add("display")
```

and inside

> return response.json().then(function (data) {
> result.innerHTML = data.clcInput.value;

i have tried to add and change it to:

```
clcInput.value = innerHTML.result;
```

what am i doing wrong?
what is wrong with my syntax and what is the order i need to write everything?
thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly what is you need, you should look at the small snippets I did below. It show a loader during the API Call and hide it when you get the result as well as updating the info paragraph depending on the value you typed.

The main thing I recommend you changing in order for your code to work properly is not adding or removing a class to your spinner element to hide it and show it, but simply changing directly it's style by using `loader.style.display = "value"`

Hope it helps.

```js
const clcBtn = document.getElementById("calcButton");
let clcInput = document.getElementById("calcInput");
const result = document.getElementById('paragraph');
const loader = document.getElementById('spinner');
clcBtn.addEventListener("click", calcFunc);

function calcFunc() {
  paragraph.innerText= "";
  loader.style.display = "block";
  
  // TimeOut to simulate API Call
  setTimeout(function() {
    loader.style.display = "none";
    if (clcInput.value > 50) {
      paragraph.innerText = clcInput.value + " - Error, value too high";
    } else {
      paragraph.innerText = clcInput.value + " - Value correct";
    }
  }, 2000);
}
```

```css
#spinner {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 5px solid black;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="calcInput" />
<button id="calcButton">calcButton</button>
<div id="spinner"></div>
<p id="paragraph"></p>
```